# Running IO on background thread in scala cats

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, scala-cats

```
def backGroundTask:IO[Unit]={
IO
{
//Time consuming task
}
}
```

How to execute this task eagerly on a background thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ContextShift.evalOn](https://typelevel.org/cats-effect/datatypes/contextshift.html#evalon):

```
def backGroundTask = IO {
      Thread.currentThread()
}

val contextShift: ContextShift[IO] = IO.contextShift(ExecutionContext.global)

val ec = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()) //create other execution context

println(backGroundTask.unsafeRunSync()) // will print Thread[main,5,main]
println(contextShift.evalOn(ec)(backGroundTask).unsafeRunSync()) //will print Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
```

Comment: I want  behavior like future where it starts execution eagely

Comment: So why you won't use future?

Comment: Trait expects IO[Unit]. As a workaround, I have used wrapper around back gound code inside future and returned empty IO. Are you suggesting the same?

Comment: You can just use `IO.fromFuture(IO.pure(future))`